# Underline part of a word while preserving kerning

Tags: kerning, underline

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`lua-ul`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-ul)

The usual ways of underlining text (or at least the ones I know of: be it with `\underline` or e.g. the `soul` package) break kerning when used with *part* of a word. My current solution consists of a two-step process

1. I type the letters to be underlined (this takes care of the kerning with the preceding letter)
2. I type the underline
3. I grab the following letter and add the kerning manually

MWE with picture of the result

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1{%
   #1%
   \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
   \hb@xt@\z@{\hss\vrule height -1.2pt depth 1.6pt width\wd0}%
   \addkerncorrection{#1}%
}

\def\addkerncorrection#1#2{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{{#1}{#2}}%
   \setbox1=\hbox{#1#2}%
   \dimen@=\wd1
   \advance\dimen@ by -\wd0
   \kern\dimen@ #2%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

V\foo{A}V

VAV

V\underline{A}V

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that this kind of fails if the underlined part is the last piece of a word. Of course I can correct this with an empty group but I'd like to avoid that. I have a working trick (which I refuse to post here `:-)`) based on `\new@ifnextchar` from `amsgen` to test for a following space character but I'm starting to grow uncomfortable with the level of hacking. Furthermore, when `utf8` encoding is used it breaks down for stuff like `l\foo{ie}ß`, which should be thus input as `l\foo{ie}\ss`.

So the question is: **Is there a (better) way to underline part of a word while preserving the correct kerning and not swallowing spaces?**

For those who might think this is an XY problem: this is about typesetting psalms in the different tones, like

[image]

Comment: luatex an option?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I have to `:-)` Jokes aside, yes, of course. My desire of having this working is stronger than my distaste for stuff I don't understand... `:-)`

Comment: for classic tex I'm pretty sure i'd use a syntax `\foo{Kr}{a}{ft}` with the pre, underlined, and post groups separate and possibly empty, then you don't have to mess with ifnextchar tests,  for luatex you could perhaps use a callback to add the lines after typesetting

Comment: Point is, I'm working for someone else. The idea would be to have an environment which makes `_` active, and use `Kr_a_ft`. With my current solution (plus the bit I haven't shown) spaces are not a problem, but `ß` are. But I start to think that the question is ill-posed `:-(`

Comment: ß should't be a problem I'd have thought, if they are your example should include that case:-)

Comment: In the question I did mention that `l\foo{ie}ß` raises issues. Nothing that can't be cured by `l\foo{ie}{ß}` though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using LuaTeX, you can use the new [`lua-ul`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-ul) package which also allows e.g. nested underlines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lua-ul,luacolor}
\usepackage{tikzducks,pict2e}

\newunderlinetype\myunderduck{\cleaders\hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5ex,y=.5ex,baseline=.8ex]%
      \duck
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\newunderlinetype\myunderwavy{\cleaders\hbox{%
    \setlength\unitlength{.3ex}%
    \begin{picture}(4,0)(0,1)
      \thicklines
      \color{red}%
      \qbezier(0,0)(1,1)(2,0)
      \qbezier(2,0)(3,-1)(4,0)
    \end{picture}%
}}
\newcommand\underDuck[1]{{\myunderduck#1}}
\newcommand\underWavy[1]{{\myunderwavy#1}}
\begin{document}
V\underLine{A}V

\underDuck{VAV}

\underDuck{V}\underLine{AV}

\underDuck{These are \underWavy{ucks}}

\strikeThrough{Dinner is ready!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Old answer (this later became `lua-ul`)

Using LuaTeX, you can use an attribute to mark the characters you want to underline. This does not interfere with kerning/ligaturing/line breaking because it only acts after all this is finished.

I added some extra flexibility for customized line thickness, placing, duck underlines, ... but the callback basically just iterates over the node tree and draws leaders whenever it finds a marked node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikzducks,pict2e}

\newattribute\underlineattr
\begin{luacode*}
  local underlineattr = token.create'underlineattr'.index
  local underline_types = {}
  function new_underline_type()
    table.insert(underline_types, tex.box[0].head)
    tex.box[0].head = nil
    tex.sprint(#underline_types)
  end
  local add_underline_h
  local function add_underline_v(head)
    for n in node.traverse(head) do
      if head.id == node.id'hlist' then
        add_underline_h(n)
      elseif head.id == node.id'vlist' then
        add_underline_v(n.head)
      end
    end
  end
  function add_underline_h(head)
    node.slide(head.head)
    local last_value
    local first
    for n in node.traverse(head.head) do
      local new_value = node.has_attribute(n, underlineattr)
      if n.id == node.id'hlist' then
        new_value = nil
        add_underline_h(n)
      elseif n.id == node.id'vlist' then
        new_value = nil
        add_underline_v(n.head)
      elseif n.id == node.id'kern' and n.subtype == 0 then
        if n.next and not node.has_attribute(n.next, underlineattr) then
          new_value = nil
        else
          new_value = last_value
        end
      elseif n.id == node.id'glue' and (
          n.subtype == 8 or
          n.subtype == 9 or
          n.subtype == 15 or
      false) then
        new_value = nil
      end
      if last_value ~= new_value then
        if last_value then
          local width = node.rangedimensions(head, first, n)
          local kern = node.new'kern'
          kern.kern = -width
          kern.next = node.copy(underline_types[last_value])
          kern.next.width = width
          kern.next.next = n
          n.prev.next = kern
        end
        if new_value then
          first = n
        end
        last_value = new_value
      end
    end
    if last_value then
      local width = node.rangedimensions(head, first)
      local kern = node.new'kern'
      kern.kern = -width
      kern.next = node.copy(underline_types[last_value])
      kern.next.width = width
      node.tail(head.head).next = kern
    end
  end
  local function filter(b, loc, prev, mirror)
    add_underline_v(b)
    local new_prev = mirror and b.height or b.depth
    if prev > -65536000 then
      local lineglue = tex.baselineskip.width - prev - (mirror and b.depth or b.height)
      local skip
      if lineglue < tex.lineskiplimit then
        skip = node.new('glue', 1)
        node.setglue(skip, node.getglue(tex.lineskip))
      else
        skip = node.new('glue', 2)
        node.setglue(skip, node.getglue(tex.baselineskip))
        skip.width = lineglue
      end
      skip.next = b
      b = skip
    end
    return b, new_prev
    -- return node.prepend_prevdepth(b)
  end
  luatexbase.callbacktypes.append_to_vlist_filter = 3 -- This should not be necessary
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('append_to_vlist_filter', filter, 'add underlines to list')
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\newunderlinetype[2]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{#2\hskip0pt}%
  \chardef#1=\directlua{new_underline_type()}\relax
}
\newunderlinetype\myunderline{\leaders\vrule height-1ptdepth1.5pt}
\newunderlinetype\mystrikethrough{\leaders\vrule height2.5ptdepth-2pt}
\newunderlinetype\myunderduck{\cleaders\hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=3,scale=0.05]%
      \duck
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\newunderlinetype\myunderwavy{\leaders\hbox{%
    \setlength\unitlength{.3mm}%
    \begin{picture}(4,0)(0,1)
      \thicklines
      \color{red}%
      \qbezier(0,0)(1,1)(2,0)
      \qbezier(2,0)(3,-1)(4,0)
    \end{picture}%
}}
\newcommand\underLine[1]{{\underlineattr=\myunderline#1}}
\newcommand\underDuck[1]{{\underlineattr=\myunderduck#1}}
\newcommand\underWavy[1]{{\underlineattr=\myunderwavy#1}}
\newcommand\strikeThrough[1]{{\underlineattr=\mystrikethrough#1}}
\begin{document}
V\underLine{A}V

\underDuck{VAV}

\underDuck{V}\underLine{AV}

\underDuck{These are \underWavy{ucks}}

\strikeThrough{Dinner is ready!}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result]

Comment: -1 for the ducks:-)

Comment: +1 but give me some more time to digest this before I accept `:-)` One thing (besides the whole lua code) is not clear to me: what's the purpose of `\newcount`?

Comment: @campa A "underlinetype" is basically just a number identifying the stored  leader specification. This leads to the question how to store this number under a nice name. There are three options: Creating a macro with the written out number, using a TeX count register or a (math)chardef. Using a macro can lead to parsing problems related to trialing spaces, so I avoided them. `chardef`s are nice but hard to set from Lua (This will probably change in the next LuaTeX version). So a `\count` register is used to store the number. Before setting it, it has to be allocated by `\newcount`.

Comment: I just edited the code, now the `\newcount` is gone and a `\chardef` is used instead.

Comment: Is there a _simple_ way to use this luacode for a new command like `\strikeThrough`. I tried to adapt the measurments but didn't succeed. `{\leaders\vrule height+4ptdepth1.5pt}` is obviously not correct.

Comment: If my text is long enough I ran eventually into a `error: [\directlua]:50: attempt to index field 'prev' (a nil value)`. Any ideas about this? For small documents this works fine. Luatex 1.0.4

Comment: @LeO I added a `\strikeThrough`. The trick is to set a negative depth, because you want the lower edge above the baseline.

Comment: @LeO How long is "long enough"? I just tested it with the `blindtext` package, a 20 page dummy document worked both with and without math, also a multi-page paragraph worked fine. Of course, you should never underline that much, especially not with ducks.

Comment: Hmm... I have a 200 page document. Underlines (regular) approx just one or two per page (some words and some hrefs) - roughly estimated. it compiles approx 50 to 80 pages. Than it fails with the above error. Don't know if it's related with the version of LuaTex but that version is bundled for Linux.

Comment: @LeO Can you try adding `node.slide(head.head)` between `function add_underline_h(head)` and `local last_value`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94480/discussion-between-leo-and-marcel-kruger).