# Redefine command to handle empty linebreaks

Tags: macros, underline

I have the request to use underline text. I am aware this could be done with `\ul` (from `soul` package) which works in most of the scenarios. Somehow this command has a problem to handle properly `\href{}` commands.

Despite the question if this makes sense or not I need a solution for this case. I found that `\uline` (from `ulem` package) could handle this situation much better without any problems. But now the next problem is arising, namely

```
\uline{This is a bold text 

with an empty line inbetween}
```

is not properly handled due to the empty linebreak. I have somehow in my memory this is because how the arguments of the commands are handled. I remember vague that the command needs to be redefined to hold an empty linebreak but I coudln't find a hint how to do so. Could somebody please point me toward a solution?

Note: I am using `lualatex` with the purpose to generate a PDF file. Math mode is not really a subject, meaning I don't care much about Math mode.

Comment: you are underlining whole paragraphs??? possibly using `\endgraf` instead of the blank line will work (it will allow the argument, whether `\uline` can cope with end of paragraph I do not know and you didn't provide a test file

Comment: @LeO If you use luatex anyway you could e.g. use the code from my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446444/underline-part-of-a-word-while-preserving-kerning/446488#446488). That defines an underline command using LuaTeX attributes which doesn't have any problems with paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\ul`handles this properly. So therefore I don't understand why the problem arises with `\uline`...

Comment: No idea but I would try to avoid underlining, but if you really have to, go with @MarcelKrüger's suggestion

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I'll try it. Especially I need to evaluate how `\href` is handled and empty lines. No idea about page breaks but might be an issue as well. Anyway I'll test it. Thx

Comment: Your tex-input contains two consecutive linebreaks. Tokenizing this yields a single token `\par`. If the macros underlying `\uline` are not defined in terms of `\long`, their args must not contain the token `\par` no matter how `\par` is defined. But you can do `\uline{This is a bold text\csname par\endcsname with a par-token in between}` and see that `\uline` will ignore paragraph breaking. One could define a routine which splits its arg at `\par`-tokens and does `\uline{paragraph1}\par\uline{paragraph2}\par...` but evaluating the arg and finding ends of paragraphs is a "hard" problem...

Comment: Well... If I change the second linebreak into a `\newline` than it works. But I'm interested in it to use the latex code for the text without too much of a change. I thought a redefine of the command might be helpful. Besides this the approach from Marcel sounds promising.