# lualatex 1.12 compatibilty with newcommand and arabluatex

Tags: luatex

I upgraded to the new lualatex 1.12 and it seems that I have problems with the combination of different packages and lualatex.

I tried to follow this [implementation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446488/48642) for underlining. But somehow the package `arabluatex` seems to raise compatibility issues. i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{pict2e}


\usepackage{arabluatex} % for support of arabic fonts

\newattribute\underlineattr
\begin{luacode*}
  local underlineattr = token.create'underlineattr'.index
  local underline_types = {}
  function new_underline_type()
    table.insert(underline_types, tex.box[0].head)
    tex.box[0].head = nil
    tex.sprint(#underline_types)
  end
  local add_underline_h
  local function add_underline_v(head)
    for n in node.traverse(head) do
      if head.id == node.id'hlist' then
        add_underline_h(n)
      elseif head.id == node.id'vlist' then
        add_underline_v(n.head)
      end
    end
  end
  function add_underline_h(head)
    node.slide(head.head)
    local last_value
    local first
    for n in node.traverse(head.head) do
      local new_value = node.has_attribute(n, underlineattr)
      if n.id == node.id'hlist' then
        new_value = nil
        add_underline_h(n)
      elseif n.id == node.id'vlist' then
        new_value = nil
        add_underline_v(n.head)
      elseif n.id == node.id'kern' and n.subtype == 0 then
        if n.next and not node.has_attribute(n.next, underlineattr) then
          new_value = nil
        else
          new_value = last_value
        end
      elseif n.id == node.id'glue' and (
          n.subtype == 8 or
          n.subtype == 9 or
          n.subtype == 15 or
      false) then
        new_value = nil
      end
      if last_value ~= new_value then
        if last_value then
          local width = node.rangedimensions(head, first, n)
          local kern = node.new'kern'
          kern.kern = -width
          kern.next = node.copy(underline_types[last_value])
          kern.next.width = width
          kern.next.next = n
          n.prev.next = kern
        end
        if new_value then
          first = n
        end
        last_value = new_value
      end
    end
    if last_value then
      local width = node.rangedimensions(head, first)
      local kern = node.new'kern'
      kern.kern = -width
      kern.next = node.copy(underline_types[last_value])
      kern.next.width = width
      node.tail(head.head).next = kern
    end
  end
  local function filter(b, loc, prev, mirror)
    add_underline_v(b)
    local new_prev = mirror and b.height or b.depth
    if prev > -65536000 then
      local lineglue = tex.baselineskip.width - prev - (mirror and b.depth or b.height)
      local skip
      if lineglue < tex.lineskiplimit then
        skip = node.new('glue', 1)
        node.setglue(skip, node.getglue(tex.lineskip))
      else
        skip = node.new('glue', 2)
        node.setglue(skip, node.getglue(tex.baselineskip))
        skip.width = lineglue
      end
      skip.next = b
      b = skip
    end
    return b, new_prev
    -- return node.prepend_prevdepth(b)
  end
  luatexbase.callbacktypes.append_to_vlist_filter = 3 -- This should not be necessary
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('append_to_vlist_filter', filter, 'add underlines to list')
\end{luacode*}


\newcommand\newunderlinetype[2]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{#2\hskip0pt}%
    \chardef#1=\directlua{new_underline_type()}\relax
}
\newunderlinetype\mystrikethrough{\leaders\vrule height3.5ptdepth-3pt}
\newcommand\strikeThrough[1]{{\underlineattr=\mystrikethrough#1}}
\newunderlinetype\myunderline{\leaders\vrule height-1ptdepth1.5pt}
\newcommand\underLine[1]{{\underlineattr=\myunderline#1}}


\begin{document}
V\underLine{A}V


\strikeThrough{Dinner is ready!}
\end{document}
```

result in a strange error - namely

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Command \underLine already defined.
```

The same code can be compiled properly with lualatex 1.10. Has the package `arabluatex` been changed or is now lualatex somehow more strict?

Plus is there a *simple* way to fix this problem to let luatex compile the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are referring to has been put in a package `lua-ul` and arabluatex loads this package. Simply remove your code and enjoy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\usepackage{arabluatex} % for support of arabic fonts

\begin{document}
V\underLine{A}V

\strikeThrough{Dinner is ready!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: uhu... just for the sake of clarity: Load `arabluatex` has a fix for the kerning in the underline part. So loading it won't be any longer _alone_ for the purpose of  arabfonts - which is quite strange. Is this something which might be removed again? Otherwise I rename the commands by myself...

Comment: You can load the new package `lua-ul` also yourself. Check its documentation. Marcel simply put the code of his answer in it (with some improvements) to make it generally available. And the arabluatex author liked it so much that he loads it in arabluatex to use it for his underlining commands.

Comment: Thx for the clarifications. So can simply use the `lua-ul` and if needed I'll load the `arabluatex`.